# LSTM Model in Torch not Learning

Tags: neural-network, torch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a toy dataset with one input and one output, the inputs are random 0s or 1s and the output equals the input from 3 samples previous

```
Input, Output
0,1
1,1
0,0
1,0
0,1
0,0
```

Model 1:

```
lstm = nn.Sequential()
lstm:add(nn.LSTM(1,20,8))
lstm:add(nn.Linear(20,100))
lstm:add(nn.Sigmoid())
lstm:add(nn.Linear(100,1))
lstm:add(nn.Sigmoid())
```

Model 2:

```
lstm = nn.Sequencer(
   nn.Sequential()
      :add(nn.LSTM(1,100))
      :add(nn.Linear(100,1))
      :add(nn.Sigmoid())
   )
```

Criterion:

```
criterion = nn.BCECriterion()
trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(lstm, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = .01
trainer.maxIteration = 25
```

The first model doesn't learn and the second doesn't work (possible because my data is the wrong kind for a Sequencer?)

edit:

Training:

```
lstm:training()
print("Training")
for epoch=1, 5 do
  err = 0
  for i = 1,data:size() do
    input = {}
    output = {}
    table.insert(input, data[i][1])
    table.insert(output, data[i][2])
    --input = data[i][1]
    --output = data[i][2]
    err = err + criterion:forward(lstm:updateOutput(input)[1], output)
    lstm:zeroGradParameters()
    lstm:backward(input, {criterion:backward(lstm.output[1], output)})
    lstm.modules[1]:backwardThroughTime()
    lstm:updateParameters(0.01)
    lstm.modules[1]:forget()
  end
  print (err / data:size())
end
```

I now get an error when running Model 2 through training.  The error

> AbstractRecurrent.lua:61: Missing gradInput

occurs on line

> lstm.modules[1]:backwardThroughTime()

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the first model. For the second model your input needs to be a table. Something like, `input = { }` and `input[1] = torch.zeros(1,1)` and `input[1][1] = 0` and so on. Then `lstm:forward(input)` will work.

Comment: Thanks Rudra!  I'm now getting an error when I try to run backwardThroughTime() (see edits above)

Answer (score 2):

look at the toy example for using LSTM with Sequencer. The model doesn't do anything except try to predict random numbers.

```
require 'nn'
require 'torch'
require 'rnn'

lstm = nn.Sequencer(
   nn.Sequential()
      :add(nn.LSTM(1,100))
      :add(nn.Linear(100,1))
      :add(nn.Sigmoid())
   )

-- Encapsulate thr criterion using a Sequencer
-- Just provide the entire sequence as input and the corresponding
-- target sequence as expected output
criterion = nn.SequencerCriterion(nn.BCECriterion())

data = torch.zeros(10,2)
for i=1,data:size(1) do
  data[i][1] = torch.uniform()
  data[i][2] = torch.uniform()
end

local inputs, targets = {},{}

for epoch=1,5 do
  lstm:training()

  for i=1,data:size(1) do
    --useful for minibatch
    inputs[1] = torch.zeros(1)
    inputs[1][1] = data[i][1]

    targets[1] = torch.zeros(1)
    targets[1][1] = data[i][2]

    local output = lstm:forward(inputs)
    local err = criterion:forward(output, targets)

    local gradOutputs = criterion:backward(output, targets)
    -- Sequencer handles the backwardThroughTime internally
    lstm:backward(inputs, gradOutputs)
    lstm:updateParameters(0.01)
    lstm:zeroGradParameters()

    inputs = {}
    targets = {}
  end
end
```